# Recreating a heads up notification intent. Permission Denial

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a few online delivery apps installed on my phone that create heads up notifications for new offers. When you tap the notification, that app opens directly to the new offer. If you were to say tap the app icon instead. You would have to take a few more steps to view the offer. My goal is to recreate the intent of the heads up notification from my app and skip the extra steps if I miss the notification. I have done this for a few apps and it works great! However, one in particular is a bit tricky.

This is the call made when you press the heads up notification logged via ADB:

```
10-20 15:42:15.167  1838  9696 W ActivityTaskManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { flg=0x24800000 cmp=com.driver.app/.blue.global.view.OfferActivity }
```

This is the manifest entry for that driver app:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen" android:name="com.driver.app.blue.global.view.OfferActivity" android:taskAffinity="com.driver.app.offers" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:noHistory="true"/>
```

My Java code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName(utils.grubPackage(), "com.driver.app.blue.global.view.OfferActivity"));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Of course, I've tried a few variations. But the exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.driver.app/.blue.global.view.OfferActivity } from ProcessRecord{ced60d0 659:com.please.myapp/u0a307} (pid=659, uid=10307) not exported from uid 10312
```

How would I call this intent? I understand the activity is not exported. However, I have to imagine it is possible given the user can send the intent by tapping the heads up notification.